# Laravel + Beanstalkd: Trouble getting it to start

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, beanstalkd

I set up beanstalkd with laravel on my local environment a month back for testing purposes. Composer required it, and the note I left myself to turn the queue on was "php artisan queue:work --queue=beanstalkd --tries=3". It was working great!

However, I restarted my computer for the first time since I got it running, and I have now confirmed the queue isn't running (not a surprise), and I just need to get it started again. Running that command I posted above in my terminal just causes the given command to sit idle, which definitely wasn't happening before, and it definitely doesn't turn beanstalkd on.

My best guess is I'm missing a step that I don't remember that I did, but I can't seem to find something that works while googling the solution. Been tinkering for what I know is a really simple solution for hours now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That command will run the workers - but unless the server is also running, there is nothing for it to connect to.

How that would be started depends on how you have it setup. One common way on a linux-like system would be with `/etc/init.d/beanstalkd start`. It can be setup to auto-start on a server, but again, that depends on which OS you are using, how you have it installed and what systems you normally use.